# Cast value & get property from it in one line

Tags: swift

I'd like to write following lines into one line statement:

```
var myBool = false
if let myButton = myView.subView.button as? MyButton {
    myBool = !myButton.isValid
}
```

Is it possible to do it this way, that I have everything in short statement which will also return false if `myButton` is not the type of `MyButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it on one line, you can do something like this:

```
let myBool = !((myView.subView.button as? MyButton)?.isValid ?? true)
```

This is the most concise way I've been able to come up with that has the expected behavior you outlined.  However, it's far from easy to read.

---

The clear reason to want a single line approach however is perhaps so that `myBool` can be declared as a constant with `let`, right?

The alternative here could be a method:

```
func isValidButton(testView: UIView) -> Bool {
    guard let button = testView as? MyButton else {
        return false
    }
    return button.isValid
}
```

So this is multiple lines, but it's easier for a human to read what is going on here.  And in the calling place, it's still one line and allows for the `let` declaration of your boolean variable:

```
let myBool = !isValidButton(myView.subView.button)
```

---

And keep in mind, this doesn't even have to be a method on the class.  If you need it in just one spot, it can be a closure with local scope.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let isValidButton = { (testView: UIView) -> Bool in
        guard let button = testView as? MyButton else {
            return false
        }
        return button.isValid
    }

    let myBool = !isValidButton(myView.subView.button)

    // do some things
}
```

---

As a note here, I've only assuming that your `MyButton` inherits from `UIView` and that `UIView` is perhaps what `myView.subView.button` is declared as returning.  Realistically, your `isValidButton()` closure should take an argument of whatever type `myView.subView.button` returns (maybe it's `UIButton`) and presumably, that type is either a parent of `MyButton` or it is a protocol which `MyButton` conforms to.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for a 1-liner is to use the *nil coalescing operator* along with `map` to apply the negation:

```
let myBool = ((myView.subView.button as? MyButton)?.isValid).map{!$0} ?? false
```

Comment: While it is a very clever solution, it lands quite far from easy to read code. It obviously answers my question correctly, but I'd not use this code in production :) Making code pretty for others to read is the key to maintainable project. Anyway, once again, smart - I wouldn't think of it probably.

Comment: @Vive It's extraordinarily counter-intuitive to ask for a 1-liner solution to a problem only to critique answers which provide solutions which are hard to read.

Comment: @nhgrif I didn't only critique - I've also said it's smart (two times!), so there was positive reaction which you try not to notice. I accepted one answer and wrote under the other one, why I prefer the first one. It does the same and at the same time is easier to read, what is also important.

Comment: I'm actually curious if you accepted my answer because of the one-liner at the top or the alternatives recommended below that.  I think the first solution I propose is just as readable/unreadable as this answer's solution.

Comment: @nhgrif I think your one liner is more readable, because adding the `map` adds another level of complexity over here, while `??` is more obvious. Also I read all the alternatives you've written, but that unfortunately didn't apply to my case. Anyway, I've finished writing the code in totally different way, but both answers taught me something.

Comment: @Vive, beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  Using map is a generally useful technique to apply a function to an optional (or to return nil if the optional is nil).  The more you see it in use, the less complex it will seem. Keep it in your back pocket as a tool to be used when needed. Here it has the advantage of not requiring the default case of `false` to be inverted to `true` which I would argue helps readability once you are used to seeing `map` used with optionals.

Comment: I think both one liners are equally terribly unreadable and would never use either... But I agree there is a ton of value in vacawama's approach which doesn't invert the Boolean literal.